# PJSIP pausing/resuming streams

Tags: stream, telephony, pjsip

I'm porting a SIP app from PJSIP 1.6 to 2.4. The API changed with version 2.0 and I can't figure out how to access the media session for a call, to pause/resume a stream.

I have a call id, and I want to toggle it's stream. In the old API it was really simple:

```
const pjmedia_session* session = pjsua_call_get_media_session(call_id);
```

Now (in the 2.4 version) the process is incomprehensible for me... Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

depending on what you'd like to achieve you can do the following..

1. use pjmedia_stream_pause and pjmedia_stream_resume to stop/start RTP steams.
2. (for outbound audio) zero out microphone gain with VAD enabled.
3. (for video) use pjsua_call_set_vid_strm to HOLD/UNHOLD

if you are attempting to start and stop audio streams that are attached to a conference bridge there may be additional requirements.

Comment: Thanks for input, but this is the stuff I already know :) The trick is to get get the media session required for these actions, given only the call id. Maybe I was not clear enough what I am trying to accomplish. I ma trying to pause the ENCODING (outgoing) stream, to mute the user, but most of all, stop the outgoing data traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a session, pause/resume a stream.

```
auto& call = pjsua_var.call[call_id];
if (call.media[0].type == PJMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
    auto stream = call.media[0].strm.a.stream;
    if (stream) {
        pjmedia_stream_pause(stream, PJMEDIA_DIR_ENCODING);
    }
}
```